# View for Retina 3.5 displayed like Retina 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, user-interface

I would like to have an iPhone app only for Retina 3.5. For one of my views I set Size to "Retina 3.5 Fill Screen". I added a toolbar to this view.
However, when I run the app on iPhone 5 the view is displayed Full Screen (like on Retina 4) and the toolbar is somewhere in the middle of the view.
Here are my settings from the XCode:
[image]

And here is a screenshot from my iPhone 5:
[image]

Any thought how can I make sure that the view is displayed as Retina 3.5 on iPhone 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you don't want it to work for the 4 inch display? For iPhone five users (at least for me anyways) having an app that isn't built for the larger display is the most annoying thing ever. Those users pay to have more screen real estate and not making an app for them isn't taking advantage of that extra screen real estate. Also, apple made auto layout to be more versatile. This means in the future there are going to be even more screen sizes coming up, so sooner or later you will have to learn how to make the apps behave correctly using auto layout.

Comment: This is a utility app for my company and I don't need to support iPhone 5.

Comment: Is there a file in your project that has "-568h" in it? It will be most likely a png file. I believe if you delete that then support for the 4 inch display should be removed

Comment: No, I don't have any file like this in my project.

Comment: If you go to the target summery page, is there a launch image set for the 4 inch display?

Comment: Well if there is not launch image then the app shouldn't be going full screen. If you post some of your code setting up the app maybe I could figure something out

Comment: There must be a -568h launch image for iOS to make the app fill the whole screen. Click your project in Xcode, select the target and the "Summary" tab. Scroll down to the "Launch images" section. You will find a Retina (4-inch) launch image, which is why your app uses the full screen. Also, be aware that from 1st May 2013, Apple will reject new apps or app updates that do NOT support the 4" devices.